# Matplotlib example output significantly differs from website

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

When I run the Matplotlib [api example code: radar_chart.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html) on my computer the output differs from the result on the Matplotlib website at a crucial point. The zero values, of which there are plenty of them, do not hit the origin of the chart on the Matplotlib website, see the chart at the link. When I run the exact same code on my own computer the zero values do hit the origin. See picture below. This results in a less smooth and readable chart compared to the one on the Matplotlib website, however this is not what one would expect. Could anyone please tell me why this difference exists?

[image]

Comment: Something must have changed in the update from matplotlib 1.5 to 2.0. See the [old example](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/api/radar_chart.html), which is exactly how your plot looks like. At the moment I'm not sure where this difference comes from.

Comment: Obviously the specs of the 'default' style is changed. You can list all available style with command `print(plt.style.available)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this difference is that the linked example is produced using matplotlib 2.0, while on your computer you run <= 1.5.
It can be observed when looking at the [old example](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/api/radar_chart.html) on the matplotlib page.

This difference is due to the [**axes margins**](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html) being set to `0` in matplotlib 1.5 and to `0.05` in matplotlib 2.0.
There are several ways to set the margins, one being `plt.margins(x=0.05, y=0.05)`.

Since here you want to have the same margins for all axes, one easy method is to use [rc params](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). Adding

```
plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0.05
plt.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0.05
```

at the top of the script, will set the margins to the values used by default in matplotlib 2.0. Of course you can play around with them and see which values best fit your needs.